# Vue.js: Computed value for class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my view I have the following conditional class:

```
<td class="text-center" v-bind:class="{ positivity }"></td>
```

and in my component I have the following:

```
positivity: function() {
    var type = typeof this.transaction.weeks != "undefined"
    var positive = 'green-bold'

    if ( type ) {
      positive = 'red-bold'
    }

    return positive
}
```

...but then my computed class shows as:

```
<td class="text-center positivity"></td>
```

regardless of the result of `positivity()`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
v-bind:class="positivity"
```

or :

```
v-bind:class="{ 'green-bold': !positivity, 'red-bold': positivity }"
```

and

```
positivity: function() {
    return typeof this.transaction.weeks != "undefined";
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Not sure why I included the curly braces